# Execute tap in pipes in right order and ignore results

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I can't correctly execute tap functions in observables.

I have a few related requests to API and each need to use response from previous, so I store required for next response data in class properties, so each of my pipe has tap function for assignment properties. I need only execute each of it right order. And ignore results from observables. Also my obesrvables it's promises after convertation with from(promise).

I tried to use concat and flatMap, but on some reason execute only first  request.

I missed something meaningful.

I don't want to user nested subscribers.

Eg few of my observables.

```
getPrices()
    const source = from(
      this.priceService.requestPrices(
        myParams
      )
    );
    return source.pipe(tap(response) => {
      this.requiredField = response.requiredField
    })
```

```
convertPrices()
    const source = from(
      this.priceService.convertPrices(
        this.requiredField
      )
    );
    return source.pipe(tap(response) => {
      this.oneMoreRequiredField = response.oneMoreRequiredField
    })
```

I expect only sequence execution of my tap functions and not nested code.

Comment: flateMap was changed into mergeMap. Maybe that was just the broblem. If thant's not the case can you post more of your code or maybe create a reproduction of your Problem in stackbliz?

Comment: How many requests do you want to execute? Do you know the number of requests beforehand?

Comment: @fridoo Yep, I know. I want to execute 3 sequence requests.

Comment: @LukasS, Here is primitive example of how it works. But I want to get rid of nested subscribers.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jemnop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just chain your requests with `switchMap`.

```js
getData1().pipe(
  switchMap(responseFrom1 => getData2(responseFrom1)),
  switchMap(responseFrom2 => getData3(responseFrom2))
).subscribe(responseFrom3 => console.log('complete'))
```

As your `getDataX` functions emit one value and then complete it doesn't matter whether you use `switchMap`, `mergeMap` or `concatMap`.